# fetch rows from table on basis of custom week order

Tags: mysql

finding records within a week, i tried this

```
SELECT * FROM tblbulletin WHERE YEARWEEK(publisheddate) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)
```

but it returned the records as like calendar week.  I.E. the records were between sunday and saturday of a current week.

how can i write a code to set different start of week? and how to display records within custom start of week to custom end of week?

Answer (score 2):

You can include a value for the mode argument which will set what the first day of the week is. If no mode is included the default is to select Sunday as the first day.

See http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/yearweek.php for a list of the different modes available.

Answer (score 0):

as @gerard says, use [YEARWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) with the optional `{mode}` value set to 1 - for week starting monday e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM tblbulletin WHERE YEARWEEK(publisheddate,1) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE,1)
```

NOTE: [WEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) has a table with the other possible values for `{mode}`